# Prove that the below two sets are submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology

I was asked to prove that the sets $$X_1=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\in \mathbb{R}^4: \sum x_i^2=1, x_1x_2x_3=1\}$$
And $$X_\epsilon=\{(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4,z_5)\in \mathbb{C}^5: z_1^5+z_2^3+z_3^2+z_4^2+z_5^2=0,\sum |z_i|^2=\epsilon$$
Are indeed smooth submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^4$ and $\mathbb{C}^5$ respectively. My general idea was to show that they are level sets of a submersion, but it’s still difficult to compute the tangent vectors to the two spheres (especially when the dimension is high). Is there an easier, quicker, by-definition way to do this?

Comment: I'm hesitant to write it out all the way, but I at least found it easier to check that the set of singularities for these two algebraic varieties is empty. For instance, in the real case, recall that the singularity set for $F^{-1}(0)$, $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^c$ is defined by equations $F(x) = 0, \text{rank} JF(x) < c$ where $JF$ is the Jacobian (ignoring some algebraic subtleties that don't matter here).

Comment: Why do you need to compute the tangent vectors to the spheres?

Answer (score 1):

Yes: in fact one can, instead of considering the conditions as two maps
$$f_1=\sum x_i^2,f_2=x_1x_2x_3-1,$$
We may consider the single function $$f:\mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^2,f(x)=(f_1,f_2)$$
Then, compute and show that the Jacobian has full rank in the subset.